# Why my Stripe Webhook function is not working(test mode)?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I has create a webhook php to trigger the paymentintent event status. I had successfully tigger it but the function of detected event is no working which i just want to redirect to another page if successful or not. I try to echo text, it also not showing. I can see the response body(show the text that i want to echo" in the dashboard of Stripe. Did i misunderstanding the concept of it ? This is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: webhook
*/
include_once(get_template_directory_uri().'/customFile/stripe-php-7.71.0/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxx'); // this is true, i just replace with xxx

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

$paymentstatus = "Payment Failed";

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
      );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        //handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        echo"Success";
        echo "<script>location.href='http://localhost/wordpress/';</script>";

        break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        //handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        echo "<script>location.href='http://localhost/wordpress/shop/';</script>";
        break;
}

http_response_code(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are requests that come from Stripe to your web server. There's no user attached to these events so trying to redirect after you receive a webhook event makes no sense. All that's happening is you're sending a `<script>` string back to Stripe, who promptly ignores it because all they are about is the response status code.

If you want to redirect your user after they've made a successful payment, you should either that on the client after they've [confirmed the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-submit-payment) or in your `success_url` if you're [using Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#success-page).

Comment: thanks for reply. Can i know what should i do to send the successful or fail data to another page after trigger the event. I am not using the checkout, i am using Stripe element and it will display the drop down list to let user click and direct to corresponding url. The payment method is FPX.

Comment: Webhooks are used to do purchase fulfilment, for instance you'd use them to note in your database that a payment was successful. If you want to redirect your FPX user you'd do that on the client after they've confirmed the payment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/fpx/accept-a-payment#submit-payment

Comment: so the webhooks is auto handle which not need to let stripe know the url if u has a public php file with the library code that provided by Stripe and u can update the database in switch case. And return url is the page to redirect after confirm the payment ?